# Changing limit and sup

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Let be $ A $ a set of convergent sequences. Suppose $$ b_n:=\sup\{a_n:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\} $$
does exist for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $. Then for $ (b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ follws $$ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_n=\sup\{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\} $$.

**My idea:**

> Let be $ A $ a set of convergent sequences described by
> $$ A:=\{(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \text{  converges}\}. $$
> So for all $ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A $ applies the following
> $$ \forall \varepsilon>0 \ \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \ \forall n\geq N: |a_n-a|<\varepsilon, $$
> and $ a-\varepsilon<a_n<a+\varepsilon $ with $ a:=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n $.
> Suppose $$ b_n:=\sup\{a_n:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\} $$
> does exist for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $. Because of $$ \left(\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n\right)-\varepsilon=a-\varepsilon<a_n $$
>
> the value $$ \sup\{a:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\} $$
> also does exist.
> Then
> $$ \begin{align}&\sup\{a:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\}-\varepsilon\\&=\sup\{a-\varepsilon:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\}\\&<\sup\{a_n:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\}\\&<\sup\{a+\varepsilon:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\}\\&=\sup\{a:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\}+\varepsilon\end{align} $$
> By Squeeze theorem we get
> $$ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_n=\sup\{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n:(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A\}. $$

Does this work?

Comment: I wouldn’t use $n$ in two different ways in your definition of $b_n.$

Comment: In any event, it is not true. What happens if $b_k=+\infty?$ It is easy to make $b_k=+\infty$ if $k$ is even and $b_k=1$ if $k$ is odd.

Comment: One thing to note is that $a$ depends on the sequence. So you can’t use the same $a$ over all the sequences. (But even if all the sequences converge to the same value, it still isn’t true.)

Comment: Why is $ b_k=\infty $ possible? All sequences are convergent. So also bounded by a real number.

Comment: Each sequence is bounded, but not by the same number. Let $$a_{m,n}=\begin{cases}m&n\leq m\\1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ Then for each $m\in\mathbb N,$  $(a_{m,n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $1,$ but each $b_n=+\infty.$

Comment: I forgot that $ b_n $ has not to be bounded only if it exists for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $. And yours is an example for it. Although $ b_n $ exists for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ it diverges.

Comment: Actually, you can easily make $b_n=(-1)^n,$ so even if $b_n$ is bounded, the series diverges. Let $a_{mn}=1$ if $n$ is even and $n\leq m$ and $-1$ otherwise.